# JSPDF 2.3.0 with IE11 in SharePoint on premise not loading

Tags: internet-explorer-11, jspdf, sharepoint-2016

I am trying to use jsPDF.umd.js in SharePoint to create some pdfs in an enterprise environment.
Sadly I have to rely on IE11 in this environment.

I am loading the jsPDF with script tags

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/xxxx/polyfills.umd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/xxxx/jsPDF.umd.js"></script>
```

and try to create an object with
new jspdf.jsPDF();

This works in Firefox and Edge, but Internet Explorer seems to not load the jsPDF.umd.js at all.

The error seems to be

```
SCRIPT1047: In strict mode, function declarations cannot be nested inside a statement or block. They may only appear at the top level or directly inside a function body.
File: jsPDF.umd.js, Line: 744, Column: 5
```

I am at a loss, because this works in ff and edge, but not in IE.
The sample (http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/#) site works with all browsers.

Is there a way to disable strict mode?

I never had problems with use strict before - though I do not know if and where it is activated.

I am not JavaScript developer - so maybe there is a completely different issue at work here.

edit:
the issue seems to be IE with javascript. I commented the lines with error from jspdf.umd.js out, and now I am getting a syntax error at line 847

```
let protection = 192;
```

maybe IE is using a pre ECMAscript 5 engine?

edit2:
navigator.userAgent
outputs
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Zoom 3.6.0)"

so I think I am in compatibility view - switching Document Mode seems to fix the issues - I don't know how to proceed from here yet, because this cannot be a general solution for all users.

edit3:
so the page contains

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

so I will need to change that I guess.
Maybe these articles will help:
https://www.dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2020/03/rendering-a-single-sharepoint-page-in-ie-using-edge-mode/
https://paultavares.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/how-to-render-a-sharepoint-page-in-ie-using-edge-mode-without-changing-the-master-page/

Comment: Can you please inform us of the status of the issue? does your issue solve with the answer I provided you on this thread? If yes, I suggest you mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. Thanks for your understanding. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I was able to ignore IE11 for now and can use Edge/FF. If I can revisit the issue with IE, I will probably put the page into a new frame, to not have it loaded in compatibility view.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, I understand that JSPDF can work with the **IE 11** or **Edge** document mode. But Sharepoint site contains the meta tag that loads the site in the **IE 10** document mode. That breaks the JSPDF functionality.

To fix the issue, you need to load the site in the `IE=edge` mode.

You simply need to update your SharePoint's master page to target the latest version of IE, to update your master page, follow these simple steps.

Step 1: **Download master page file.**

- Go to Site Settings.
- Then to master pages and page layouts.
- Look for the HTML version of your master page. If you are using Seattle as a master page for the site, look for the seattle.html file. If you're using the Oslo master page, then look for the oslo.html file.

Step 2: **Update the master page code.**

- Open the downloaded file into a text editor of your choice, and look for the following meta-tag.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />`

- Update the value of the content attribute to have:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

- Now Save the file.

**Note:** The meta tag might be placed multiple times in your master page file, make sure to update them all.

Step 3: **Upload master page file.**

- On the **Master pages and page layouts**  click the ribbon bar, and click **Upload Document** button.
- Now Choose the file you have just edited by clicking the **Choose File** button, then click **OK** to upload.
- Another dialog will appear asking you to enter some information about the master page. Don't type anything, just click **Check In** button.
- One last step you need to do is to make your changes available to all of your site visitors, which is to publish this master page.
- To do that, **Select** your master page, and click the **Publish** button from the ribbon bar.
- To proceed with publishing click OK on the next dialog.

Reference:

[IE Compatibility with SharePoint and Office 365](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000248726-ie-compatibility-on-sharepoint-and-office-365)